Docker multi stage builds - php-fpm-alpine and httpd-alpine
I am trying to wrap my head around the multi stage building of docker images. My requirements are such that I need to combine httpd (or even nginx) with the php-fpm alpine image, but I do not know in which order should I build them, nor which files to copy over from one to the next.
If I do FROM php:8.3-fpm-alpine as php and FROM httpd:alpine3.20 as server will all the configurations I do in the php step (installing required packages and such) be copied over to the server step?
Currently, I have them all separate in their own dockerfiles and they are working correctly, but for the life of me cannot figure out the multistage part in order to confine with my requirements.
Thank you for any advice.

Each step in a multistage Dockerfile are completely separate. They might as well be in separate files. The only way to transfer anything from one stage to another is to COPY --from=... files into the next stage. As for your scenario, the common way is to have a single process in each container, so in your case, you'd run httpd in one container and PHP in another. You can run multiple processes in a container, but it's not that common.

Yeah, I thought so, I just wanted to confirm with someone with more experience. So, basically, for php-fpm we do not have an alternative like the php-apache image?

The 'Docker' way to run multiple processes like httpd and php-fpm is to run each process in a separate container. To understand if that's good or bad for you, I'd need to understand why you're running PHP outside of Apache and I'd need to understand why you think it's undesirable to run multiple containers. As I said, you can run multiple processes in a single container, but since one of the goals of Docker is to isolate processes, it's not done often and generally considered a 'smell'.

I understand the basic and main concept of docker containers, so that each process runs in its own separate container. I am trying to create a "future proof" base of my project, and since php-apache does not support HTTP/2 (with the mod_php), I am pushed into using php-fpm, and with that, with your priceless comments, I will need to make two images (with specific configs), one for the httpd and one for th php-fpm.

You'll probably experience the least amount of pain with 2 containers. And it's easy to orchestrate multiple containers with docker compose. So that's the way I would go.

Thank you so much for this debate, I needed some reasurance how to tackle this. Thank you again.
